# Keras resume training on a new architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

I'm trying to resume the training of a simple NN architecture after a modification of it. 
Using the MNIST dataset, in this example, I train the model for 2 epochs and then I save the model in `.h5` file. Then I reload the model, I modify the model and I recompile it. But I want to resume the training exactly where I left it off. So I would like to use the optimizer of the reloaded model to continue the training. Here is the code:

```
MLP = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
MLP.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.5), loss=tf.losses.log_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
training_output = MLP.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=2, initial_epoch=0)

MLP.save('test.h5')



MLP = keras.models.load_model('test.h5', custom_objects={'log_loss': log_loss})
modelt = MLP
modelt = # update modelt architecture


modelt.compile(optimizer=MLP.optimizer, loss=tf.losses.log_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])
training_output = modelt.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=2, initial_epoch=2)
```

The problem is that:

```
Epoch 1/2

 - 1s - loss: 1.2690 - acc: 0.2216 - val_loss: 1.3097 - val_acc: 0.2095

Epoch 2/2

 - 1s - loss: 1.2859 - acc: 0.2030 - val_loss: 1.2420 - val_acc: 0.1760

Epoch 3/4

 - 1s - loss: 2.8945 - acc: 0.0993 - val_loss: 2.9367 - val_acc: 0.0890

Epoch 4/4

 - 1s - loss: 2.9035 - acc: 0.0993 - val_loss: 2.9367 - val_acc: 0.0890
```

The training remains somehow stuck or worse. How can I resolve this issue? Even trying to instanciate a new Adam Optimizer object and resetting all the values that I can touch, the behaviour does not change. What is the proper procedure to reuse a reloaded optimizer?

Thank you very much for you help!

EDIT:
A simple save and reload of the model returns this results:

```
lr begin: 0.15811755
begin: [0.35258077597618104, 0.1265]
lr end: 0.25961164
end: [1.0754492826461792, 0.2785]
-------------------------------------------------------------
lr begin: 0.25961164
begin: [1.0754492826461792, 0.2785]
lr end: 0.34131044
end: [1.5968322057723998, 0.2185]
-------------------------------------------------------------
lr begin: 0.34131044
begin: [1.5968322057723998, 0.2185]
lr end: 0.3903688
end: [2.8819153175354004, 0.106]
-------------------------------------------------------------
lr begin: 0.3903688
begin: [2.8819153175354004, 0.106]
lr end: 0.42264876
end: [2.8819153175354004, 0.106]
```

Comment: You're trying two things at the same time. Can you please first check that you're able to resume training the same architecture without any issues? After this step, please try modifying the architecture.

Comment: It seems that the loss values are moving strangely, but the model is correctly reloaded. The starting loss on validation at epoch 3 is the same loss on the validation at the end of epoch 2.

Comment: How exactly are you updating the model architecture?

Comment: I agree with @ManojMohan though. First see if reloading the model and continuing training without changing the model architecture works

Comment: I modified the question including the results. I report the learning rate at the beginning and the end of each epoch and the loss and accuracy on the validation set.

Comment: I only just noticed that you start with a learning rate of 0.5. That is quite high, meaning you run the risk of exploding gradients. It looks to me a bit like that is what is happening here. I.e. after three epochs your weights are so big that they become NaN and can no longer change. Try a smaller learning rate like 0.001 for example. Also consider normalising your inputs to values between 0 and 1

Comment: The values of the inputs are already normalized between 0 and 1. But the weights are saved alongside the model, right? So the training should be resumed perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189893/discussion-between-thenoblesix-and-karl).

Answer (score 1):

*I've entered on chat to discuss this question with @TheNobleSix and reached in an answer there, but he didn't feedback me there. So, I am writing it here in order to help a future similar problem that other user could have.*

---

When reloading a model, you **should not recompile the model** as described in [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-whole-models-architecture-weights-optimizer-state)! This causes the optimizer to lost its previous state. And this is what was happening when you tried to achieve each part of the task individually as suggested in the comments.

Having this in mind, depending on what modifications do you want to do in your model, maybe it became not suitable to continue the training at the same point or become very hard to adjust the updated model for a training continuation from the same loss/accuracy value. An alteration in the parameters number could consequently change drastically the objective function. For instance, if you change the number of neurons in a layer or add a new layer, you would need to initialize the new neurons. A possible workaround for this would be the redistribution of the layer weights (if it was the first case) among the neurons. A consequence of this is the loss of possible patterns that this layer had already identified.

I know that the previous paragraph is very speculative. If you describe the specific modification that you are doing in the architecture I could try to give you a more precise answer about the model update part.